# Why JVM uses max 40% of CPU?

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, jvm, cpu

The problem is: on load peaks CPU stucks on 40% and the request answers slow down.
I have dedicated backend API server with real load ~7,332 hits/min.
Database is on dedicated server and load is OK.
Almost no IO ops on this machine.
12 cores x 2 CPU = 24 cores
OS: OS Linux, 4.4.0-98-generic , amd64/64 (24 cores)

java version "1.7.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.11) (7u151-2.6.11-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.151-b01, mixed mode)

Tomcat 7.0.82

```
-Xms50g
-Xmx50g
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
```

Used BIO (same thing), now use NIO connector.

```
 <Connector port="8080" redirectPort="8443"
      protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
      maxThreads="2000"
      minSpareThreads="20"
      acceptCount="200"
      acceptorThreadCount="2"
      connectionTimeout="20000"
      processorCache="-1"
      URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Stats from JavaMelody

```
Busy threads = 121 / 2,000 
Bytes received = 8,679,400,308
Bytes sent = 83,345,586,407
Request count = 6,169,418 
Error count = 961 
Sum of processing times (ms) = 2,396,325,165 
Max processing time (ms) = 4,168,515
Memory: Non heap memory = 275 Mb (Perm Gen, Code Cache),
Buffered memory = 5 Mb,
Loaded classes = 48,952,
Garbage collection time = 1,238,271 ms,
Process cpu time = 197,922,070 ms,
Committed virtual memory = 66,260 Mb,
Free physical memory = 267 Mb,
Total physical memory = 64,395 Mb,
Free swap space = 0 Mb,
Total swap space = 0 Mb
Perm Gen memory:    247 Mb / 512 Mb
Free disk space:    190,719 Mb
```

Can't reproduce this on test server.
Where is my bottleneck?

[CPU usage chart from JMX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiC2P.png)
[htop stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwu6u.png)
Update:
[Profiler screenshot TaskQueue.poll() hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF0Jf.png)
[Profiler screenshot ordered by self time CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NCTH.png)

Comment: Are you sure that any of hard limits not set https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpu?

Comment: Have you tried a profiler?

Comment: @apangin, yes, visulavm shows TaskQueue.poll() 58%

Comment: Sort by `Self time (CPU)` and skip native methods doing I/O. Other top methods will be responsible for CPU utilization. Or try [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) - it usually shows more accurate results.

Comment: @apangin, thanks for the help, I added screenshots of the profiler. Andrey, I was on your lecture about profiling on JPoint 2017:) it's not the question about, what do we need to refactor, but what did we misconfigure.

Comment: Well, the profile suggests there are at least two places where an application waits for incoming data from outside: 1) Spring HTTP remoting; 2) PostgreSQL client. Any of them can be a bottleneck in throughput and prevent your application from utilizing CPU at maximum.

Comment: As to TaskQueue.poll - it just shows that Tomcat thread pool is idle - nothing strange here.